# How do you construct the following bean with xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring

How do you construct the following bean with xml configuration?

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    public ResteasyClient restClient() {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                .establishConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .socketTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to implement `FactoryBean` interface:

```
public class ResteasyClientFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<ResteasyClient>{

    private int connectionTimeout;
    private int socketTimeout;


    public ResteasyClient getObject() throws Exception {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                    .establishConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .socketTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();;
    }

    public Class<? extends ResteasyClient> getObjectType() {
        return ResteasyClient.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setConnectionTimeout(int connectionTimeout) {
        this.connectionTimeout = connectionTimeout;
    }

    public void setSocketTimeout(int socketTimeout) {
        this.socketTimeout = socketTimeout;
    }
}
```

And add to config following bean definition:

```
<beans ..."> 
   <bean name="myResteasyClient" class="ResteasyClientFactoryBean">
       <property name="connectionTimeout" value="xxx"/>
       <property name="socketTimeout" value="xxx"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Then you can inject this bean to another beans, it will be resolved as `ResteasyClient` instance.